# Can not load or initialize mscordaccore.dll when analyzing a core dump with dotnet-dump analyze

Tags: debugging, .net-core, coredump

I am trying to analyze a core dump using dotnet-dump tool via cmd:

```
tmp>dotnet-dump analyze core.2293 
Loading core dump: core.2293 ... 
Ready to process analysis commands. Type 'help' to list available commands or 'help [command]' to get detailed help on a command. 
Type 'quit' or 'exit' to exit the session.
```

As documentation tells it brings up an interactive session that accepts a variety of instructions to get debug info.

In my case, every command fails with the message like this:

```
> pe -lines
Failed to load data access module, 0x80004002
Can not load or initialize mscordaccore.dll. The target runtime may not be initialized.

For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135652
>
```

p/s Link above doesn't help much.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The limitation is that process dumps are not portable. It is not possible to diagnose dumps collected on Linux with Windows and vice-versa.

The dump was collected on a Linux machine. And I were trying to analyze it on a Windows machine.

To analyze it properly you should set up a Linux environment. In my case, it was done by creating a docker container with an sdk:alpine image.