# How to analyze dotnet dump created in production container?

Tags: .net, .net-core

My app is running on production in `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine` container. I was able to create dump with `dotnet-dump collect` tool/command (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/diagnostics-in-containers) and download it to my mac (I have file named "gql-dump" on my mac). Now I want to analyze it (somehow). I tried with my local dotnet tools:

```
$ dotnet-dump analyze gql-dump 
Loading core dump: gql-dump ...
Ready to process analysis commands. Type 'help' to list available commands or 'help [command]' to get detailed help on a command.
Type 'quit' or 'exit' to exit the session.
> dumpheap -stat                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Failed to find runtime module (libcoreclr.dylib), 0x80004002
Extension commands need it in order to have something to do.
For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135652
```

I tried also to do this from a container running on my mac (also mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine):

```
$ ./dotnet-dump analyze gql-dump 
Loading core dump: gql-dump ...
Ready to process analysis commands. Type 'help' to list available commands or 'help [command]' to get detailed help on a command.
Type 'quit' or 'exit' to exit the session.
> dumpheap -stat                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Failed to find runtime module (libcoreclr.so), 0x80004002
Extension commands need it in order to have something to do.
For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135652
```

I read somewhere that I need some symbols and tried (also on desktop and from container):

```
# in mac terminal
$ dotnet-symbol --host-only gql-dump                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
Downloading from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/
ERROR: Invalid ELF BuildID '<null>' for /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
ERROR: Invalid ELF BuildID '<null>' for /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
ERROR: Invalid ELF BuildID '<null>' for /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1

# in container
$ ./dotnet-symbol --host-only gql-dump                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Downloading from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/
ERROR: Invalid ELF BuildID '<null>' for /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
ERROR: Invalid ELF BuildID '<null>' for /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
ERROR: Invalid ELF BuildID '<null>' for /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
```

How can I make this work? Also from what I read to analyze the dump I need symbols from my app actually - how can I get them? Do I need to "download" image that runs on production to my mac to get the symbols? Or maybe I should exactly same image as on production for analysis?

Also I am aware of [Can not load or initialize mscordaccore.dll when analyzing a core dump with dotnet-dump analyze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70078621/can-not-load-or-initialize-mscordaccore-dll-when-analyzing-a-core-dump-with-dotn) and this is why I tried to analyze the dump in a container based on the one that runs on production (`mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine`).

---

Here is how it looks like when I try to download symbols:

```sh
/tools # ./dotnet-symbol gql-dump 
Downloading from http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/
Writing: ./createdump
Writing: ./createdump.dbg
ERROR: Invalid ELF BuildID '<null>' for /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1
ERROR: Invalid ELF BuildID '<null>' for /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.28
Writing: ./libmscordaccore.so
Writing: ./libmscordaccore.so.dbg
ERROR: Invalid ELF BuildID '<null>' for /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
/tools # ls
createdump              dotnet-counters         dotnet-symbol           gql-dump                libmscordaccore.so.dbg
createdump.dbg          dotnet-dump             dotnet-trace            libmscordaccore.so
/tools # ./dotnet-dump analyze gql-dump
Loading core dump: gql-dump ...
Ready to process analysis commands. Type 'help' to list available commands or 'help [command]' to get detailed help on a command.
Type 'quit' or 'exit' to exit the session.
> dumpheap -stat                                                                                                                             
Failed to find runtime module (libcoreclr.so), 0x80004002
Extension commands need it in order to have something to do.
For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135652
>
```

Answer (score 1):

## dotnet-dump error

To resolve the error ”Failed to find runtime module (libcoreclr.dylib)” ensure that work directory, dump file and symbol files directory are in the same directory.

## Downloading symbols

The dotnet-symbol tool can download modules and symbols needed to analyze the dump.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-symbol

## Dotnet Diagnostics FAQ

This FAQ covers how to resolve dotnet-dump relaterade errors.
https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics/blob/main/documentation/FAQ.md

Comment: It did not help me - see last updated in my question.